# need help getting the max time

Tags: sql

```
SELECT
    jobname, stepname, ExecutionStatus, runtime 
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT
         j.name JobName, h.step_name StepName, 
         CONVERT CHAR(10), CAST(STR(h.run_date, 8, 0) AS dateTIME), 101)  RunDate, 
         STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST(h.run_time AS VARCHAR(6)), 6), 5, 0, ':'), 3, 0, ':') RunTime,
         CASE h.run_status 
            WHEN 0 THEN 'FAILED'
            WHEN 1 THEN 'Succeeded' 
            WHEN 2 THEN 'Retry' 
            WHEN 3 THEN 'Cancelled' 
            WHEN 4 THEN 'In Progress' 
         END AS ExecutionStatus 
     FROM 
         msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory h 
     INNER JOIN 
         [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs] j ON j.job_id = h.job_id
     WHERE 
         j.name NOT LIKE '%PDM %' 
         AND j.name NOT LIKE '%PDM_Push%' 
         AND j.name NOT LIKE '%&PDM_%' 
         AND j.name NOT LIKE '%CDM%') AS IJ
WHERE 
    RunDate >=CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
    AND ExecutionStatus = 'FAILED' 
    AND stepname NOT LIKE '(job outcome)'
    AND RunTime > CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD (HOUR , -4 , GETDATE() ), 108)
GROUP BY
    ij.jobname, IJ.StepName, ij.RunDate, IJ.RunTime, IJ.ExecutionStatus
ORDER BY
    rundate DESC
```

I have this query and the result is giving multiple results like below:

```
jobname stepname    ExecutionStatus (No column name)
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  13:08:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  13:11:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  13:20:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  13:23:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  13:26:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  13:29:31
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  13:38:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  13:41:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  13:44:31
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  13:53:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  13:56:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  13:59:31
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  14:08:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  14:29:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  14:32:31
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  14:35:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  14:38:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  14:41:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  14:44:31
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  14:47:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  14:50:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  14:53:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  14:56:31
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  14:59:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  15:02:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  15:05:31
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  15:08:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  15:11:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  15:14:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  15:17:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  15:20:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  15:23:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  15:26:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  15:29:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  15:32:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  15:35:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  15:38:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  15:41:31
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  15:44:31
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  15:47:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  15:50:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  15:53:31
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  15:56:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  15:59:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  16:02:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  16:05:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  16:08:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  16:11:31
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  16:14:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  16:17:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  16:20:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  16:23:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  16:26:31
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  16:29:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  16:32:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  16:35:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  16:38:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  16:41:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  16:44:31
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  16:47:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  16:50:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  16:53:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  16:56:30
sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  16:59:30
```

I just want the max time for the job name, how can I do that?

Comment: What's your expect result?

Comment: If you want the max time for the job name then you would just do a max function on the column that is providing you with the time field. MAX is an aggregate so you would probably group by the name and status and such so that you retrieve the single row per job name.

Comment: Can you add some sample input data, and a description of your table structure (e.g. DDL)?

Comment: my expected result should just be only this result and not all the above 
 sp_who2 logging sp_whoisactive  FAILED  16:59:30

Answer (score 0):

This query show last status per job.

```
SELECT 
    NOME AS NAME,
    STEP,
    STATUS,
    DT_INICIO AS DATE,
    DURACAO AS DURATION,
    SERVIDOR
FROM (SELECT 
    B.NAME AS NOME,
    C.STEP_NAME AS STEP,
    CASE 
WHEN RUN_STATUS = 0 THEN 'FALHA'
WHEN RUN_STATUS = 1 THEN 'SUCEDIDO'
WHEN RUN_STATUS = 3 THEN 'CANCELADA'
WHEN RUN_STATUS = 4 THEN 'EXECUTANDO' ELSE '' END [STATUS],
    CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR,RUN_DATE)),103) + ' ' +
CASE LEN(H.RUN_TIME)
WHEN 1 THEN CAST('00:00:0' + CAST(H.RUN_TIME AS CHAR) AS CHAR (8))
WHEN 2 THEN CAST('00:00:' + CAST(H.RUN_TIME AS CHAR) AS CHAR (8))
WHEN 3 THEN CAST('00:0' + LEFT(RIGHT(H.RUN_TIME,3),1) +':' + RIGHT(H.RUN_TIME,2) AS CHAR (8))
WHEN 4 THEN CAST('00:' + LEFT(RIGHT(H.RUN_TIME,4),2) +':' + RIGHT(H.RUN_TIME,2) AS CHAR (8))
WHEN 5 THEN CAST('0' + LEFT(RIGHT(H.RUN_TIME,5),1) +':' + LEFT(RIGHT(H.RUN_TIME,4),2) +':' + RIGHT(H.RUN_TIME,2) AS CHAR (8))
WHEN 6 THEN CAST(LEFT(RIGHT(H.RUN_TIME,6),2) +':' + LEFT(RIGHT(H.RUN_TIME,4),2) +':' + RIGHT(H.RUN_TIME,2) AS CHAR (8)) END,103) AS DT_INICIO,

CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR,RUN_DATE)),103) + ' ' +
CASE LEN(H.RUN_DURATION)
WHEN 1 THEN CAST('00:00:0' + CAST(H.RUN_DURATION AS CHAR) AS CHAR (8))
WHEN 2 THEN CAST('00:00:' + CAST(H.RUN_DURATION AS CHAR) AS CHAR (8))
WHEN 3 THEN CAST('00:0' + LEFT(RIGHT(H.RUN_DURATION,3),1) +':' + RIGHT(H.RUN_DURATION,2) AS CHAR (8))
WHEN 4 THEN CAST('00:' + LEFT(RIGHT(H.RUN_DURATION,4),2) +':' + RIGHT(H.RUN_DURATION,2) AS CHAR (8))
WHEN 5 THEN CAST('0' + LEFT(RIGHT(H.RUN_DURATION,5),1) +':' + LEFT(RIGHT(H.RUN_DURATION,4),2) +':' + RIGHT(H.RUN_DURATION,2) AS CHAR (8))
WHEN 6 THEN CAST(LEFT(RIGHT(H.RUN_DURATION,6),2) +':' + LEFT(RIGHT(H.RUN_DURATION,4),2) +':' + RIGHT(H.RUN_DURATION,2) AS CHAR (8)) END,103),108) AS DURACAO,
(SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,RB) + CASE WHEN (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,RA)) IS NULL THEN '' ELSE '\'+ (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,RA)) END 
FROM (SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceName') AS RA, ConnectionProperty('local_net_address') AS RB) AS R
) SERVIDOR,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY B.NAME,C.STEP_NAME ORDER BY 
    CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR,RUN_DATE)),103) + ' ' +
CASE LEN(H.RUN_TIME)
WHEN 1 THEN CAST('00:00:0' + CAST(H.RUN_TIME AS CHAR) AS CHAR (8))
WHEN 2 THEN CAST('00:00:' + CAST(H.RUN_TIME AS CHAR) AS CHAR (8))
WHEN 3 THEN CAST('00:0' + LEFT(RIGHT(H.RUN_TIME,3),1) +':' + RIGHT(H.RUN_TIME,2) AS CHAR (8))
WHEN 4 THEN CAST('00:' + LEFT(RIGHT(H.RUN_TIME,4),2) +':' + RIGHT(H.RUN_TIME,2) AS CHAR (8))
WHEN 5 THEN CAST('0' + LEFT(RIGHT(H.RUN_TIME,5),1) +':' + LEFT(RIGHT(H.RUN_TIME,4),2) +':' + RIGHT(H.RUN_TIME,2) AS CHAR (8))
WHEN 6 THEN CAST(LEFT(RIGHT(H.RUN_TIME,6),2) +':' + LEFT(RIGHT(H.RUN_TIME,4),2) +':' + RIGHT(H.RUN_TIME,2) AS CHAR (8)) END,103) DESC) AS D

FROM MSDB.DBO.SYSJOBHISTORY H
JOIN MSDB.DBO.SYSJOBS B
ON H.JOB_ID = B.JOB_ID
JOIN MSDB.DBO.SYSJOBSTEPS C
ON H.JOB_ID = C.JOB_ID
AND H.STEP_ID = C.STEP_ID
WHERE RUN_DATE = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),112) ) AS SRC
WHERE D = 1
```